# Modifying an existing hash value by x and returning the hash

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to increment all values of a hash by a given amount and return the hash. I am expecting:

```
add_to_value({"a" => 1, "c" => 2,"b"=> 3}, 1) 
# => {"a" => 2, "c" => 3,"b"=> 4}
```

I'm thinking:

```
def add_to_value(hash, x)
  hash.each {|key,value| value + x}
end
```

This returns:

```
{"a"=>1, "b"=>3, "c"=>2}
```

Why is hash sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're super close, without any extra gems needed:

```
def add_to_value(hash, x)
  hash.each {|key,value| hash[key] += x }
end
```

Just iterate the hash and update each value-by-key. #each returns the object being iterated on, so the result will be the original hash, which has been modified in place.

If you want a copy of the original hash, you can do that pretty easily, too:

```
def add_to_value(hash, x)
  hash.each.with_object({}) {|(key, value), out| out[key] = value + x }
end
```

That'll define a new empty hash, pass it to the block, where it collects the new values. The new hash is returned from `#with_object`, and is thus returned out of `add_to_value`.

Comment: But this modifies the original hash in place.

Comment: Should `hash.each {|key,value| hash[value] += x }` change to `hash.each {|key,value| hash[key] += x }` ? And out[value] = `value + x ` should be `out[key] = value + x`

Answer (score 0):

The problem becomes trivial if you use certain gems, such as `y_support`. Type in your command line `gem install y_support`, and enjoy the extended hash iterators:

```
require 'y_support/core_ext/hash'

h = { "a"=>1, "c"=>3, "b"=>2 }
h.with_values do |v| v + 1 end
#=> {"a"=>2, "c"=>4, "b"=>3}
```

As for your sorting problem, I was unable to reproduce it.

Of course, a less elegant solution is possible without installing a gem:

```
h.each_with_object Hash.new do |(k, v), h| h[k] = v + 1 end
```

The gem also gives you `Hash#with_keys` (which modifies keys) and `Hash#modify` (which modifies both keys and values, kind of mapping from hash to hash), and banged versions `Hash#with_values!`, `#with_keys!` that modify the hash in place.

Comment: Thanks! Any way I can do it without requiring a gem?

Comment: I already added the option without requiring the gem. Also, you can just spork the `Hash#with_values` and `Hash#with_values!` (which modifies the hash in place) from the gem.

Comment: @Зелёный, this is a matter of opinion. Excessive parenthesis do not make the oneliner more readable to me. And, btw, `{}` have their specific use eg. if I wanted to write `h.each_with_object Hash.new { |k, h| h[k] = 42 } do |(k, v), h| ... end`. `{}` bind tighter than `do ... end`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to increment values:

```
 hash = {}
 {"a" => 1, "c" => 2,"b"=> 3}.each {|k,v| hash[k]=v+1}
 hash
 =>{"a"=>2, "c"=>3, "b"=>4}
```

And the hash will be sorted as you want.